# How can i push pop in swreveal view controller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app like Facebook. I want to push and pop in swreveal view controller. How can achieve this? Check following image.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AppCoda did a tutorial using the SWRevealViewController awhile back. They give pretty detailed instructions. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: @Erik please check image..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have a storyboard like this:

[image]

In LoginViewController:

```
    @IBAction func skip(_ sender: Any) {
    // Show dashboard

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardNavigationController")

    revealViewController().setFront(controller, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func validateUser(_ sender: Any) {
    // show profile

    // Here test for valid user name and password
    // If OK
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let dashboardNC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

    let profileVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
    dashboardNC .pushViewController(profileVC, animated: false)

    revealViewController().setFront(dashboardNC, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func dismissKeyboard(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

In MenuTableViewController (SideMenu):

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    // ...
    let dashboardNC = revealViewController().frontViewController as! UINavigationController
    let nc = revealViewController().frontViewController as! UINavigationController
    let vc = nc.topViewController

    if !(vc is ProfileViewController) {
        // Instantiate controller from story board
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
        dashboardNC.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
    }

    // Push it with SWRevealViewController
    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(dashboardNC, animated: true)
}
```

DashboardViewController:

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var revealButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    revealButton.target = revealViewController()
    revealButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

    rightButton.target = revealViewController()
    rightButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

    revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()
    revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()

    revealViewController().rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0
    revealViewController().rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0
}
```

Not Objective-C but you can easily translate!

Comment: can you please convert in objc

Comment: No, it's so simple that you can make the effort for this, I think.

Comment: i am new in ios

Comment: Yes, then you have to learn with the Apple's documentation. It is highly recommended!

Comment: please help me out of this...I know navigation but  it's third party thats why I am confued

Comment: Can you try to do something and show us? That's the best advice I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you have to manager Login/Dashboard through rootViewController of window.

**Step 1:**
In your AppDelegate write a method, call for example `setupRootVC()`

```
func setupRootVC(){
    if userIsLoggedIn{
       window.rootViewController = yourSWRevealControllerObj
    }else{
       window.rootViewController = yourLoginControllerObj
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Call `setupRootVC()` method from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

**Step 3:** In your `LoginVC`, after user logged in successfully call AppDelegate's `setupRootVC()` method.

**Step 4:** Make sure `frontViewController` of `SWRevealController` is inside `UINavigationController` so that your can push and pop through it.

I suggest you to read more about iOS app architecture and how `rootViewController` and `UINavigationController` works.
Hope that helps.

Comment: can you give demo..in objective c

Comment: Tell me what have you tried, Stackoverflow is not for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to push from swreveal to any controller

```
UIStoryboard*Storyboard=[AppDelegate storyBoardType];
    yourController  *your=(yourController*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourControllerId"];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: your];

    [navController setViewControllers: @[your] animated: YES];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

        }
```

from any controller to swreveal view controller you have to add this line in your action click

```
 [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UINavigationController's method :

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

but please note that it sets whole Navigation controller stack.
so you probably will have to take your current view controller state
from the property

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *> *viewControllers;
```

allocate a new

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController viewControllers];

[controllers addObject:VC1];
[controllers addObject:VC2];
[controllers addObject:VC3];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```